Хранение и воспроизведение больших объемов данных (петабайт)
Какая аппаратная/программная архитектура предпочтительна для хранения и репликации петабайт данных?

Смотря что нужно делать с этими данными.

Apache Hadoop HDFS или Amazon S3 позволяют хранить большие объемы данных
